# Cordova-ios 4.3.0 Push is not working on iOS 10

Tags: cordova-ios

With Xcode 8.1 and Cordova 6.4.0 Push app is failing to register on iOS 10.
Same app works if we have old Cordova plugin or with Xcode 7.3.5 & Cordova 6.4.0.
Enabled the Push capabilities in Xcode. No errors shown in Xcode log.

Answer (score 0):

Both Xcode 8.1 and Cordova 6.40 are outdated, update Xcode & Cordova to latest levels and also take latest MFP Push sample apps from here http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/handling-push-notifications/cordova/.

This should resolve your issue.